# Powershell: MaskedTextBox get Text

Tags: powershell, passwords, maskedtextbox

How can I get the plain text of a Maskedtextbox?

For example like this:

```
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$MaskedTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$MaskedTextBox.PasswordChar = '*'
$MaskedTextBox.Top = 100
$MaskedTextBox.Left = 80
$Form.Controls.Add($MaskedTextBox)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$MaskedTextBox.Text` contains your input.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this, I get no value.
What I tried:
$Password = $MaskedTextBox.Text
$Password

Comment: Execute your script and enter the password. Now close the script and check the console with `$MaskedTextBox.Text` or `$Password`.

Answer (score 1):

Your $form is missing an OK/Cancel button, see [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-5)

So simply copy/pasted from cited link:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\08\14\SO_51841162.ps1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$MaskedTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$MaskedTextBox.PasswordChar = '*'
$MaskedTextBox.Top = 100
$MaskedTextBox.Left = 80
$Form.Controls.Add($MaskedTextBox)

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$Result = $Form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $x = $MaskedTextBox.Text
    "Entered hidden password is: {0}" -f $x
}
```